# MongoError - caused by npm module connect-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongoose, connect-mongo

Im getting these errors

> MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
>
> MongoError: Topology was destroyed

i'd love if anyone would know what is causing this module to make these errors and how to fix it.
.

> MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
>       at basicWriteValidations (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:698:41)
>       at Server.update (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:834:16)
>       at Server.update (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/topology_base.js:326:25)
>       at updateDocuments (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:1344:19)
>       at /home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:437:24
>       at new Promise ()
>       at executeOperation (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:432:10)
>       at Collection.update (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:829:10)
>       at withCallback.collectionReady.then.collection (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:244:48)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>   MongoError: Topology was destroyed
>       at nextFunction (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:603:27)
>       at Cursor.next (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:824:3)
>       at Cursor._next (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:211:36)
>       at nextObject (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:186:10)
>       at next (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:165:3)
>       at executeOperation (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
>       at Cursor.next (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:253:10)
>       at findOne (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:542:10)
>       at /home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:437:24
>       at new Promise ()
>       at executeOperation (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:432:10)
>       at Collection.findOne (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1021:10)
>       at withCallback.collectionReady.then.collection (/home/jnyheim/var/www/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:192:46)
>       at

I found that its caused by this 
`const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);` 
module while executing

> store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "mylittle34secret",
    cookie: { maxAge: (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    proxy: true,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
}));
```

full code:

```
'use strict'

// Dependencies
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session'); 
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const path = require('path');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/app', {useNewUrlParser: true, socketTimeoutMS: 0, keepAlive: true, reconnectTries: 30}, (err, db)=>{
if(err){
    console.log('## INCOMMING MONGO ERROR ##' + err + '## MONGO ERROR END ##');
    throw err;
}else{
    console.log("-->  succesfully connected to Database!");
};

//db.once('')
});




const paypal_config = require('./lib/helpers/paypal_configuration.json');

paypal.configure(paypal_config);


const app = express()

// Root Routes
const _shop = require('./route/shop');
const _index = require('./route/index');
const _about = require('./route/about');
const _session = require('./route/session');
const _projects = require('./route/projects');


// View Engine
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
extname: '.hbs',
defaultLayout:'layout',
layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'
}));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder | Public Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

// Express Session
app.use(session({
secret: "mylittle34secret",
cookie: { maxAge: (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) },
saveUninitialized: false,
resave: false,
proxy: true,
store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),

}));

// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Body Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
    var namespace = param.split('.')
    , root    = namespace.shift()
    , formParam = root;

  while(namespace.length) {
    formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
  }
  return {
    param : formParam,
    msg   : msg,
    value : value
  };
}
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Vars for HTML doc   
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
res.locals.warning_msg = req.flash('warning_msg');
res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
res.locals.info_msg = req.flash('info_msg');
res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
res.locals.user = req.user || null;
res.locals.session = req.session;
next();
});

// root/routes
app.use('/', _index);                // x/
app.use('/shop', _shop);             // x/shop
app.use('/about', _about);           // x/about  
app.use('/session', _session);       // x/session
app.use('/projects', _projects);     // x/projects

// Server
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 80));

app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=>{
console.log('-->  HTTP Server started on port %s', app.get('port'));
});
```

<3

Comment: What version of express are you using?

Comment: I'm using "express": "^4.16.3"

Comment: Have you tried with the [Advanced connection](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo#re-use-a-mongoose-connection)  option?